# What is the difference in a Beastmaster's animals?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, familiars, animal-companions

A [Beastmaster](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Beastmaster_(5e_Class)) (homebrew class) has both an animal familiar and a companion. My question is, what is the difference? I've looked them over and can't find any.

Comment: Just looking through the list of features in the table of contents, I can see a number of differences between the two. What exactly is the part that confuses you? Also, keep in mind that dand wiki has a lot of homebrew material. The class that you are referencing looks to be unofficial homebrew content, not an official expansion of the ranger class.

Comment: Are you asking to compare this to what's in the book, or specifically the variations/variants listed at that site?  In asking this question, what problem are you trying to solve.  Does this influence your choice of PC, your choice of Ranger sub class, or something else related to the game you are playing?

Answer (score 1):

The most notable difference between animal familiars and companions is that the familiar can not directly attack. See the evolution section of the link you provided and note:

> ### Unnatural Selection
>
> At level 5, the familiar may take evolution points from the companion's evolution to use on themselves. The familiar can only take evolutions that it meets the prerequisites for. Remember, the familiar CANNOT attack.

Also note the hit dice calculations. Your familiar has half your hit points rounded down, and your companion uses whatever hit dice are listed in their monster manual entry.